# CVXPY constraint formulation

Tags: cvxpy, cvxopt

I'm creating a long short market neutral portfolio using following function.

```
import cvxpy as cp
def create_gross_exposure_constraint(w):
    return cp.norm1(w)  <= 2
def create_market_neutral_constraint(w):
    return cp.sum(w) == 0
```

I'm trying to add net asset value constraints as explained below:

I want the net exposure < 1 Million USD (this number can be changed). What does this mean is If i do allocation using above weight: abs(Position_of_Asset * Price_of_Asset) < 1 Million USD.

I tried creating it using below. But it is not working.

```
def create_value_exposure_constraint(w, idx):
    x = cp.sum(cp.abs(w))
    return w[idx] / x  <= 0.1
```

Comment: Instead of ``a/b<=0.1`` write ``a<=b*0.1``.

Comment: And actually: you will not be able to use ``cp.abs(w)`` in this context because it will be on the wrong side of inequality to remain convex. This sort of constraint will require an exact model of 1-norm using binary variables an mixed-integer optimizer https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#exact-1-norm

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Can you please tell me how can i add that formulation of the mosek here?